# CSS Grid and Angular: How to make an L-shaped component that the empty cell' can be filled with other elements in other components?

Tags: css, angular, css-grid, grid-layout

Consider the code below

sccs:

```
.my-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 25px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "a b"
  "a .";
  .a{
      grid-area: a;
      background-color: red;
  }
  .b{
      grid-area: b;
      background-color: green;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="a">aaaaaaa</div>
  <div class="b">bbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

How can I use `my-grid-component` in another component and fill the empty cell with content **without** using angular's `<ng-content></ng-content>`.
For example, see the code below from another component:

```
<my-grid-component></my-grid-component>
<div>some content I want to fill the empty cell</div>
```

See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGeGs.png). How can I fill the "c" cell in another component without `ng-content`?